# How to open two differrent URLsat the same time using urllib.request.urlopen in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I want to know if anyone knows how to open 2 different URLs at the same time using  urllib.request.urlopen? I can only open one URL at a time so far using try and except:

```
try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.6", timeout=5).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash, "FAIL")  
    sys.exit(0)
    
except urllib.error.URLError:
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("IP address: 192.168.100.5 is reachable")
```

How can i open both URLs at the same time and when 192.168.100.6 is reachable then the system just exits as you can clearly see in my code. But if 192.168.100.5 is reachable then the programm continues to function.
How can I open both 192.168.100.6 & 192.168.100.5 at the same time and then using urllib or some other method and print "Fail" if 192.168.100.6 is reachable and print "Pass" if 192.168.100.5 is reachable.

I have read into threading but i really do not know how to implement it so please help me guys, show me how this could be done I really have no clue and i am so confused after reading about threading multi threading aiohttp aiosync I am just so confused.
If someone could show me how it is done I could use that as a base to understand what is going on.

I am just a beginner so please take it easy on me all.

Comment: If you're a beginner I wouldn't recommend you diving into `threading`, `asyncio` or `multiprocessing`, it's a really difficult topic for beginners.

Comment: I'd recommend trying the requests module.  It is a lot more friendly to beginners. 
 https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thank you for your reply but is there another way?

Comment: In your code, you are not instantiating the request, just saving the response code.